# Flutter switch change value with tap instead of sliding (unable to get focus)

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a CupertinoSwitch which works great for sliding but I would also like it to change it when I tap on it.

I tried wrapping it in an inkwell and a gesture detector and setting the value like this:

```
                                   GestureDetector(
                                      child: CupertinoSwitch(
                                        value: notificationsAllowed,
                                        activeColor: Colors.orange,
                                        onChanged: (notificationsSelection) {
                                          userProfile
                                              .userNotificationsPermitted =
                                              notificationsSelection;
                                        },
                                      ),

                                      onTap: (){
                                        setState(() {
                                          print ('tapped');
                                          notificationsAllowed = true;
                                        });

                                      },
                                    ),
```

But what I have found is that the inkwell is not registering the tap, I assume because it is not gaining focus.

I tried both inkwell and gesture but I am not sure why it is not registering the tap event.

Thanks

Comment: in material design there is SwitchListTile, have you tried it out, i believe there is  an alternative for Cupertino Widgets.

Answer (score 1):

```dart
    GestureDetector(
      child: Container(
        width: 42.0,
        height: 24.0,
        color: Colors.white,
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(21.0),
        child: CupertinoSwitch(
          value: notificationsAllowed,
          activeColor: Colors.orange,
          onChanged: (notificationsSelection) {
            userProfile
                .userNotificationsPermitted =
                notificationsSelection;
          },
        ),
      ),

      onTap: (){
        setState(() {
          print ('tapped');
          notificationsAllowed = true;
        });

      },
    ),
```

but CupertinoSwitch onChanged method not work!

Answer (score 1):

GestureDetector won't work on top of CupertinoSwitch. Both of them cannot handle a tap simultaneously and hence only one of them will work at a time.

> I would also like it to change it when I tap on it.

I'm not sure what you mean by this. If you want to change the state of switch as on or off, you can do it by changing the value property of CupertinoSwitch. Since you're using notificationsAllowed as value for CupertinoSwitch, change it's value in onChanged.

```dart
CupertinoSwitch(
          value: notificationsAllowed,
          activeColor: Colors.orange,
          onChanged: (notificationsSelection) {
            notificationsAllowed = !notificationsAllowed;  //add this
            userProfile
                .userNotificationsPermitted =
                notificationsSelection;
          },
        ),
```